# Windows 8 Wifi does'nt even scan for network and displays no conections are available

Tags: wireless-networking

For past two weeks my wifi does'nt work.

i was trying to install drivers for mediatek preloader for firmware update in my micromax unite 2.finally preloader does'nt install and wifi does'nt work

> I have qualcamm atheros ar9485 802.11b/g/n wifi adapter
>
> i have windows 8 32bit on a 64bit based hp 246 G1 notebook pc
>
> ican use the wifi in linux as i had dual boot linux with windows 8
>
> all the drivers and adapters are working fine in device manager.
>
> in the task bar a red circle with a white Cross which is displayed on grey signal bar.
>
> when i point my curser it showes "Not connected-no connections are available"
>
> also i did multiple reboots,enabling and disabling drivers.
>
> my laptop does'nt have any hard ware key. It contains a function key that glows blue and enable
>
> when i open device manager

Network adapters

> microsoft kerel debug network adapter
> qualcomm atheros wifi adapter
> realtek pcle pe family controller
> unknown device
> unknown device

any solutions is recommended?

Comment: did you checked if you have a fn(function) key to enable that or if you are running anu 3rd party software managing your wireless conections?

Comment: Yes i have a function key but it doesn't seemed to enable or disable networkS.always a blue light glows

Comment: Seems you have 2 missing drivers under network adapters. This may be the problem.